# What is the best way to enforce HTML Encoding on a JSP page, especially when invoked directly from web browser URL

Tags: spring, jsp, security, spring-mvc, html-encode

I am using spring 3.1.1. I am trying to HTML encode my incoming request parameters. The call to my JSP page can be made manually by a user passing in a URL from a command line tool or Web browser.

lets assume I have a request as below with request parameter as language
    http://localhost:8080/testdomain/createaccount.do?language=eng

I want to HTML encode the 'language' request parameter. I have already set a context-param in web.xml to html encoding.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Questions

1. Specifying the defaultHtmlEscape within the web.xml does not escape the html elements in the request parameter. Doesn't seem to be working? Any suggestions on how to get this working?
2. If I call the below inside the controller? Would this even help as the parsing must have already been done?

   HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(request.getParameter(language))"
3. At the specific spring controller for this page, how do I ensure Html encoding before reading the request parameter?
4. I want to understand options where I can enforce html encoding at the application level and at the page/controller level?

Answer (score 0):

The web descriptor property will apply to Spring tags only.  Use:

```
<form:input path="/my/path" htmlEscape="true" />
```

Make sure you are protected against XSS when using `HtmlUtils.htmlEscape`

What you need is just a `@RestController`

To read a parameter from the URL it is better to use `@RequestParam`

```
public @ResponseBody String myRequest(@RequestParam("language") String language) { 
    System.out.println("Language is: "+ language);
}
```

Check https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: 1. Unfortunately, the app that i work on does not use annotations. So how can I address this without annotations.   2. I am trying to address a vulnerability issue, so the URL can be called directly from the browser or say using a tool like 'curl'. So the request parameter might not come from a form input.

Comment: Spring MVC version?  I think this is more of a design problem.  If you update your question with the requirements you might get better suggestions and possible directions.

Comment: 3.1.1 Spring version. Sorry thought I had specified it in the original post, but looks like the version number was posted only partially as the first line was deleted by mistake.

Comment: @RequestParam is available since 2.5.  So, use it.  org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam